# Why can't I use private on a Realm property

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to store an enum case in RealmSwift. But Realm doesn't support enums. [This article](https://medium.com/it-works-locally/persisting-swift-enumerations-with-realm-io-dab37cd98bcd) suggests a cool solution. In it they prepend `private` to the one property in the Realm class so as to prevent it from being set or read from outside the class, and then use some getters and setters on another property to read and write to that private property.

Here is my version of that solution:

```
@objcMembers
class PlaylistRealmObject: Object {

    dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var created: Date = Date()
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    private dynamic var revisionTypeRaw: String = RevisionType.noReminder.rawValue
    var revisionType: RevisionType {
        get { return RevisionType(rawValue: revisionTypeRaw)! }
        set { revisionTypeRaw = newValue.rawValue }
    }
    let reminders = List<ReminderRealmObject>()
    let cardsInPlaylist = List<CardRealmObject>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}
```

I tried to implement the solution but found that adding `private` to the one property was causing Realm to ignore the property on the schema.

[Another article](https://forum.realm.io/t/how-to-create-custom-types/1122/2) implements the same solution but without using private. If there is a way to make a Realm property private that would be the best implementation of the solution in my view.

Is there a way to make properties in a Realm class private? If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tough to answer because our project has a similar setup and it's working. So let me try to present an answer via an example of what how our code looks.

First, the realm object. the object has an id, a name and then a visible property revisionType which is assigned via an enum (not managed by Realm) that's backed by a private revisionTypeRaw which is managed by realm.

```
class PlaylistRealmObject: Object {
    enum RevisionTypeEnum: String {
        case type_a = "a"
        case type_b = "b"
    }

    @objc dynamic var list_id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var list_name = ""

    @objc private dynamic var revisionTypeRaw: String = ""
    var revisionType: RevisionTypeEnum {
        get {
            let x = RevisionTypeEnum(rawValue: revisionTypeRaw)!
            return x
        }
        set {
            revisionTypeRaw = newValue.rawValue
        }
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "list_id"
    }
}
```

then we create a couple of playlists and store in Realm

```
let newAgePlaylist = PlaylistRealmObject()
newAgePlaylist.list_name = "New Age"
newAgePlaylist.revisionType = .type_a

let classicRockPlaylist = PlaylistRealmObject()
classicRockPlaylist.list_name = "Classic Rock"
classicRockPlaylist.revisionType = .type_b

realm.add(newAgePlaylist)
realm.add(classicRockPlaylist)
```

then to check it, load in all of the playlists and print to console depending on what type of revision they are

```
let playlistResults = realm.objects(PlaylistRealmObject.self)
for playlist in playlistResults {
    let name = playlist.list_name
    if playlist.revisionType == .type_a {
        print("name: \(name) is a type_a playlist")
    } else {
        print("name: \(name) is a type_b playlist")
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, @Jay, your solution works. Realm Browser hides private properties and that is what was fooling me. However, I did notice the following: the only difference between your code and mine is I am using a convenience init (which I omitted from the code in my question). And that convenience init is playing havoc. But why? That is another question, posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147754/why-does-adding-a-convenience-init-to-a-realm-object-declaration-mess-with-priva

Comment: Update on the above for anyone who finds this Q&A. The problem for me was not the convenience init but that I was using `@objcMembers` at the top of the class. If I removed that and add `@objc` on the properties then everything works as would be expected.

Comment: great findings @thecloud_of_unknowing! However I would say that we don't need to remove `objcMembers` from the class declaration - instead we can put "force" `objc` to our `private var`.

Comment: @PavelVavilov The problem with using `@objcMembers` on the class declaration is it takes *ALL* of the vars in the class (dynamic) and tries to manage them. I would suggest just designating the vars you want managed indivually with `@objd dynamic var ....` as it provides a more fine grained control.

Comment: @Jay agree with you. I was thinking more about the case when you have a class with > 15 vars which you would like to store in realm database.

Comment: There is one more edge case i would keep in mind that can end up burning you. That getter/setter may look and feel like a normal keypath, but obviously realm knows nothing about it. There may be a time where you need to run a partial update on a primary key object that requires not instantiating an unmanaged instance, but using  `let object = realm.create(PlaylistRealmObject.self, value: [String, Any](_, update: .modified)` If you forget and use `revisionType` as a key, it's a NOOP

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk Not sure what you're referring to. The primary key (which is now required with MongoDB Realm Sync) is `@objc dynamic var list_id = UUID().uuidString` so when an object is created, that primary key is automatically generated and populated. `RevisionTypeEnum` is not a key, its just a realm enum.

Comment: @Jay I dont mean key as in primary key, i mean keys in a key/value dictionary when using low level CRUD operations, for example, a partial update. In that scenario you aren't interacting with an instantiated class, so you can't just pass ["id": "my-primary-key",  "revisionType": "a"], you would have to pass revisionTypeRaw which you don't really want exposed anyways. So you just have to be a little careful if you are updating/partially updating to make sure you're using the correct realm tracked property name